# Regex to find an integer within a string

Tags: java, regex, integer

I'd like to use regex  with Java.

What I want to do is find the first integer in a string.

Example:

```
String = "the 14 dogs ate 12 bones"
```

Would return 14.

```
String = "djakld;asjl14ajdka;sdj"
```

Would also return 14.

This is what I have so far.

```
Pattern intsOnly = Pattern.compile("\\d*");
Matcher makeMatch = intsOnly.matcher("dadsad14 dssaf jfdkasl;fj");
makeMatch.find();
String inputInt = makeMatch.group();
System.out.println(inputInt);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You're asking for 0 or more digits. You need to ask for 1 or more:

```
"\\d+"
```

Comment: What if you want to find same result but also all with negative - and positive + char in front? I.e. +3 or -5 or 8...

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the other solutions failed to handle `+/-` and cases like `2e3`, which `java.lang.Integer.parseInt(String)` supports, so I'll take my go at the problem. I'm somewhat inexperienced at regex, so I may have made a few mistakes, used something that Java's regex parser doesn't support, or made it overly complicated, but the statements seemed to work in [Kiki 0.5.6](http://code.google.com/p/kiki-re/).

*All regular expressions are provided in both an unescaped format for reading, and an escaped format that you can use as a string literal in Java.*

**To get a byte, short, int, or long from a string:**

```
unescaped: ([\+-]?\d+)([eE][\+-]?\d+)?
  escaped: ([\\+-]?\\d+)([eE][\\+-]?\\d+)?
```

...and for bonus points...

**To get a double or float from a string:**

```
unescaped: ([\+-]?\d(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)([eE][\+-]?(\d(\.\d*)?|\.\d+))?
  escaped: ([\\+-]?\\d(\\.\\d*)?|\\.\d+)([eE][\\+-]?(\\d(\\.\\d*)?|\\.\\d+))?
```

Comment: This still catches numbers like 099, on which java parseInt will throw NumberFormatException.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding you. `099` is converted to 99 by `Integer.parseInt()`, see: http://pastie.org/1881188

Comment: Does this still work when the number is in a string like "2-1"?  It would correctly find the first match "2", but the second match "-1" is incorrect because there the - is an operator.  You would need to use something even fancier (involving a lookbehind that would disinclude a + or - if the immediately preceding thing is also a number)

Answer (score 1):

Use one of them:

```
Pattern intsOnly = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
```

or

```
Pattern intsOnly = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres a handy one I made for C# with generics. It will match based on your regular expression and return the types you need:

```
public T[] GetMatches<T>(string Input, string MatchPattern) where T : IConvertible
    {
        List<T> MatchedValues = new List<T>();
        Regex MatchInt = new Regex(MatchPattern);

        MatchCollection Matches = MatchInt.Matches(Input);
        foreach (Match m in Matches)
            MatchedValues.Add((T)Convert.ChangeType(m.Value, typeof(T)));

        return MatchedValues.ToArray<T>();
    }
```

then if you wanted to grab only the numbers and return them in an string[] array:

```
string Test = "22$data44abc";
string[] Matches = this.GetMatches<string>(Test, "\\d+");
```

Hopefully this is useful to someone...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what PiPeep said, if you are trying to match integers within an expression, so that `1 + 2 - 3` will only match `1`, `2`, and `3`, rather than `1`, `+ 2` and `- 3`, you actually need to use a lookbehind statement, and the part you want will actually be returned by `Matcher.group(2)` rather than just `Matcher.group()`.

```
unescaped: ([0-9])?((?(1)(?:[\+-]?\d+)|)(?:[eE][\+-]?\d+)?)
  escaped: ([0-9])?((?(1)(?:[\\+-]?\\d+)|)(?:[eE][\\+-]?\\d+)?)
```

Also, for things like `someNumber - 3`, where `someNumber` is a variable name or something like that, you can use

```
unescaped: (\w)?((?(1)(?:[\+-]?\d+)|)(?:[eE][\+-]?\d+)?)
  escaped: (\\w)?((?(1)(?:[\\+-]?\\d+)|)(?:[eE][\\+-]?\\d+)?)
```

Although of course that wont work if you are parsing a string like `The net change to blahblah was +4`

Comment: I don't see any lookbehinds in those regexes.  What I see are [conditionals](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html), which are not supported in Java.

Answer (score 0):

the java spec actually gives this monster of a regex for parsing doubles.
however it is considered bad practice, just trying to parse with the intended type, and catching the error, tends to be slightly more readable.

```
DOUBLE_PATTERN = Pattern
        .compile("[\\x00-\\x20]*[+-]?(NaN|Infinity|((((\\p{Digit}+)(\\.)?((\\p{Digit}+)?)"
                + "([eE][+-]?(\\p{Digit}+))?)|(\\.((\\p{Digit}+))([eE][+-]?(\\p{Digit}+))?)|"
                + "(((0[xX](\\p{XDigit}+)(\\.)?)|(0[xX](\\p{XDigit}+)?(\\.)(\\p{XDigit}+)))"
                + "[pP][+-]?(\\p{Digit}+)))[fFdD]?))[\\x00-\\x20]*");
```