# Java Regex Finding digits in a String

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find digits in a string. I know that in finding a digit is done by \d but when I try it on a sample text like the following:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2012:11:57:36 -0500] "GET http:// localhost/ HTTP/1.1" 503 418 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11"
```

using my java code

```
Pattern test = Pattern.compile("\\d");
testLine = in.readLine(); // basically the text above 
// extract date and time log in and number of times a user has hit the page
numTimesAccess++; // increment number of lines in a count   
System.out.println(test.matcher(testLine).group());
System.out.println(test.matcher(testLine).start());
System.out.println(test.matcher(testLine).end());
```

I get an error exception stating that No Match is found. Is something wrong with my regular expression patter or in the way I am trying to access the text matching the patterns.

Comment: Thanks I got it now I appreciate everyone's help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, you should call [**Matcher.find()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) before you invoke [**Matcher.group()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28%29)

use `"\\d+"` as regex if you consider 127 as a whole single digit.

```
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group() + " " + m.start() + " " + m.end());
        }
```

Comment: I tried that and still nothing. By the way I am running this code on ubuntu linux if anything.

Comment: @jonathan1987 can you post the code that you've tried and also mention the exception as well

Comment: sure. Pattern test = Pattern.compile("\\d");
testLine = in.readLine(); // basically the text above    
System.out.println(test.matcher(testLine).group());                            and my exception thrown:                                                Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
 at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:468)
 at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:428)
 at logfilevarnish.ParseLogFile.main(ParseLogFile.java:23)

Comment: @jonathan1987 you should call Matcher.find() before you call group(), check my edit

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to find single digits, you need this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(testline);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

if you want to find non-floating-point numbers, change the regex to `"\\d+"`.

Comment: I tried that I figured I take out the while look and just run it once. The first time matcher.find() was true and then when I printed it out, I still got an exception thrown.

Comment: if you only want the first match, replace the `while` with `if`

Comment: you get the exception, because you always create a new `Matcher` instead of using just one.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **\d*** instead of \d+.
Have a look at this post-:
[Finding a Number in a string.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372148/regex-to-find-an-integer-within-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

just add and use the simple ktx:

```
 fun String.digits() = 
      Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(this).run { if (find()) group() else "" }!!
```