# how to write script on validating number from the text? for ex: i like to get numeric value "2" from field "Staus(2)"

Tags: selenium-webdriver

On Selenium, I'm writing script to get the number from the text. suppose there is a field 'Status(2)'. The number in the brackets keep changing. I want to get the value.

Comment: Assuming that the value retrieved is a string you can assign it to a variable in whatever language you are using and use the following regex to extract the number `\d+`. This can then be cast to an integer if needed.

Comment: can you please elaborate? I want to get the number from the string. for ex: 2

Comment: You need to provide some more information on the language you are using to code with selenium in that case. Post a code snippet in your question of what you already have and I may be able to help some more.

Comment: I am writing in java. On this code, trying to validate Status(2) in <span id="ctl00_ctl00_cphBMain_cphMain_lblObjects"  onmouseup="javascript:PopupMenu.setRightClick(this,document.getElementById ('divPopupMenu_Group'));" style="color:Red;cursor:pointer;">Status(2)</span>

Answer (score 0):

This code should get back the text for the element you have provided:

```
WebElement web_element_found = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_cphBMain_cphMain_lblObjects"));
String element_text = web_element_found.getText();
```

Then you can have a look at this answer for how to use regex to extract the digit from the string: [Regex to extract digit from string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13843795/6657098)

Hope this helps!

Comment: sorry! It didn't work. Its displaying Status(2) instead of "2".

Comment: Yes the 'element_text' variable should be equal to 'Status(2)'. You then need to pass that to the regex function I have linked.

Comment: Thank you! I got it. I tried the other way replacing all the characters with zero and getting the digits. It worked

Comment: @learning0112 No problem. If you have an answer you should post it in case anyone else comes across this issue at some point. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```
String rawText = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_cphBMain_cphMain_lblObjects")).getText();
String number = rawText.substring(s.indexOf("(") + 1).substring(0, s.indexOf(")"));
System.out.println(number);
```