# How to tell if an unknown number is in a String?

Tags: java, string

I have an `if` statement which checks if a variable is equal to some string. But, I want to check if there is an number in the string, too. Something like this:

```
if(thestring.equals("I, am awesome. And I'm " + Somehowgetifthereisanumberhere + " years old")) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

Or more specifically, where *x* is the unknown number, just to know there is a number (any number) there:

```
String str = item.substring(item.indexOf("AaAaA" + x), item.lastIndexOf("I'm cool."));
```

How to do that?

Comment: Looked in SO..I think this has been asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372148/regex-to-find-an-integer-within-a-string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)):

```
if(thestring.matches("^I, am awesome. And I'm \\d+ years old$")) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Also note that the double backslash is because the double backslash \\ translates to a single backslash within the string, and then the sequence \d is seen and parsed by the regular expression engine.

Comment: That's awesome, but can I somehow put this in my substring thing? Really thankful for your help :)

Comment: @GuiceU You don't; this would replace your `thestring.equals()` call.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Yes, I know. So I cannot use this somehow in my substring? Is there anything else I can use then? EDIT: Or could'nt I just use the \\d+?

Comment: @GuiceU \\d+ (actually, \d+ - see my comment above about the double backslash) is regular expression syntax, so no, you cannot use it with `String.equals()`. However, you *can* use it with `String.matches()` as Cairnarvon showed in the answer. It *is* possible to do this without regular expressions, but I'd say they are by far the best suited tool for this kind of string processing.

Comment: The regex pattern \d matches any digit, and + means repeat the previous pattern for as long as possible (otherwise you'd match only a single digit). There's more to it than that if you dig into it all, but that's the gist of it. So by having \d+ in the match expression you will match one or more digits in that position, which is what you wanted to do.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Dude, _thank you_! Seriously, you're awesome. Now to the question. Okey, I get that, so it isn't possible to use it with 'String.indexOf()' either? If not I'll just have to find another way to do this, but again. Thank you :)

Comment: @GuiceU If you need the position within the string as well, [Penelope's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16677427/486504) is probably the best way to do it. But that wasn't in the original question. Also, you may want to try [searching for questions tagged java regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+regex).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Well, doesn't work in my case. But thank you all anyway!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the regular expression.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*[^0-9].*");
```

References:

- [Using Regular Expressions to Extract a Value in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237061/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-a-value-in-java)
- http://javarevisited.blogspot.gr/2012/10/regular-expression-example-in-java-to-check-String-number.html

Answer (score 2):

This regex should find any one, two or three digit number (in case they are 102 years old) within any string:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d\\d?\\d?");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("some string with a number like this 536 in it");
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group());  //This will print the age in your string
        System.out.println(m.start());  //This will print the position in the string where it starts
    }
  }
}
```

Or this to test the entire string:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("I, am awesome. And I'm \\d{1,3} years old");  //I've stolen Michael's \\d{1,3} bit here, 'cos it rocks.
Matcher m = p.matcher("I, am awesome. And I'm 65 years old");
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group());
        System.out.println(m.start());
}
```

Comment: Michael - Sweet!  Didn't realise you could do that.  I've still got training wheels on.  lol  :-)

Comment: Hah - yeah I guess so..  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to use regular expressions. See - [Using Regular Expressions to Extract a Value in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237061/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-a-value-in-java)

To match letters 'd', 'e', or 'f', for e.g.:

```
[a-z&&[def]]
```

And also - [Lesson: Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

[Pattern class is good study too](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)