# Detecting files with sequential number in the file name

Tags: java, filenames, sequential

I want to implement a function that imports multiple files with the sequential number.
If the file names are something like `aaa_000`, `aaa_001` than I can split them by the underscore and take the number. But when the file names aren't in this pattern, I don't know what is the good way to do this.
File names could be `a_aa_000`, `a00a_000`, `a_0_000` , `aaa000`, `a_aa000` and they end with a number.

---

Update:
I found a way to achieve it by finding the last not number char, the chars before it will be the mutual name.

Comment: Just split on the last underscore?

Comment: If you want just the last number-part you can use substring in combination with lastIndexOf: filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf("_")+1);

Comment: @RobAu Sorry, I didn't make it clear, underscore isn't necessary for the name.

Comment: So the name can be anything? Or will it end with a number? Or contain a number?  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372148/regex-to-find-an-integer-within-a-string

Comment: @RobAu  It will end with a number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match last number in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320525/regular-expression-to-match-last-number-in-a-string)

Comment: What is it you want do achieve here? Do you want to import only specific files whose names follows a pattern or do you want to import multiple files and determine which ones belongs together based on their names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to what @Robabu mentioned, please change your pattern to include a "$" so that it only matches the pattern ending with the string. Below code works for all the test inputs you mentioned above.

```
Pattern intsOnly = Pattern.compile("\\d+$");
Matcher makeMatch = intsOnly.matcher("a_aa000");
makeMatch.find();
String inputInt = makeMatch.group();
System.out.println(inputInt);
```